# How to keep MenuManager opened to allows multiple selection when Action.AS_CHECK_BOX is selected

Tags: java, swt, jface

I have a context menu where there is a subsection called submenu which includes some items which each item is an Action.

What I want to do is to enable the user to be able to select multiple items without having to reopen the menu and submenu until he clicks away.

A similar problem has aready been addressed and solved, but I am confused how to keep the submenu also opened.

Here's [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12288028/how-to-keep-swt-menu-open-after-user-clicks-menu-item/25309961#25309961)!

```
public void test() {
    final TableViewer tableViewer = new TableViewer(PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getShell());

    MenuManager menuMgr = new MenuManager("#PopupMenu");
    menuMgr.setRemoveAllWhenShown(false);
    final Menu menu = menuMgr.createContextMenu(tableViewer.getControl());
    tableViewer.getControl().setMenu(menu);

    menuMgr.addMenuListener(new IMenuListener() {
        public void menuAboutToShow(IMenuManager manager) {
            manager.add(new Separator("Actions")); // Where manager is a IMenuManager which is passed as a parameter of menuAboutToShow of addMenuListener
            final MenuManager submenu = new MenuManager("Show actions");
            manager.add(submenu);

            for (final TableColumn tc : tableViewer.getTable().getColumns()) {
                Action action = new Action(tc.getToolTipText(), Action.AS_CHECK_BOX) {
                    @Override
                    public boolean isEnabled() {
                        return true;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean isChecked() {
                        return tc.getWidth() != 0;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (mainMenuPoint == null)
                            return;

                        Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {

                            public void run() {

                                menu.setLocation(mainMenuPoint);
                                menu.setVisible(true);

                                Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {

                                    public void run() {
                                        submenu.setVisible(true);

                                    }
                                });

                            }
                        });

                    }

                };
                submenu.add(action);
            }
        }


    });
}
```

This code keeps the first menu opened but not the submenu.

Any help is highly appreciated :)